# Clear logs from SQL Server Audit File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit-logging

Is it possible to  Clear `SQL Server` Audit File logs. I want to delete old logs by date but can't find a way to delete it both from interface and sql Query.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you getting a Delete option when you right click on the log? Check this link. https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/analyze-and-read-sql-server-audit-information/

Comment: I am getting 'Delete' to delete the complete file. Not the file logs.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, it is.

By [sys.server_audits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-audits-transact-sql) select old names via `create_date` column.

Then loop the names and delete them by using the next code for deleting:

```
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Audit_name] WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO
USE [master]
GO
DROP SERVER AUDIT [Audit_name]
GO
```

Comment: How to get old names ?

Comment: Will it delete the complete file or Just logs from file ? It's deleting the file i think. I want to clear the file not delete the file